# Should I glue down rubber mulch or install something else for dog run?

Tags: exterior

I have a dog run that has been turned into a race track by my two afghan hounds. Unfortunately they use the fence walls to turn around which pushes the mulch up against the walls. This is causing the fence door to flex at the bottom because it has so much pressure from the mulch. Additionally the dog run is on a hill so mulch eventually migrates from the top of the run to the bottom, further compounding the issue.

Is there a recommended mulch glue for rubber mulch or can I do something else to keep the mulch in place? I've thought of removing the mulch and putting in larger river stones but don't have the money for that project right now and also a little unsure if it will eventually result in the same issue but be heavier and harder to spread out later.

Any recommendations would be super appreciated!!! Please see pictures for reference.[image: backyard mulch]

Comment: Stones might be hard on their feet.  Large(5x8ft) rubber mats might work.  They are heavy.  I usually use a pair of locking pliers on them for handles to move.  Might just need them around the outside with the other mulching in the centre.  The people over at https://pets.stackexchange.com/  might have some other ideas.

Comment: This is something I don't know much about, but is what most children's playgrounds are done in these days in the UK - it's a poured, rubber mulch in a resin base, porous but stays put. Looks like tarmac but is 'squishy'. One UK manufacturer for info - https://www.softsurfaces.co.uk/wet-pour-construction/

Comment: @crip659 that is a good idea but I think I'd have the same issue if the loose mulch were in the middle.

Comment: @Tetsujin I've thought about that but trying to avoid any major renovations with this area until next year as it isn't in the cards this year to do anything too crazy.

Comment: Have you considered Astroturf, or one of the modern nicer-looking equivalents?

Comment: Recommendation - use a rake, daily if needed, to redistribute the mulch.